# MIB compiler for Java

Tags: java, snmp, mib, snmp4j

I am going to develop SNMP Manager using snmp4j and i have MIB files from hardware vendor. Programming using digital OID is inconvenient. Is there a compiler from MIB file(s) to corresponding Java classes that support getting digital OID needed by SNMP protocol? Or the best way is to parse MIB files using Mibble in runtime?

Comment: Is the MIB from the vendor likely to change a lot? That might affect the answer to this question.

Comment: SNMP managers usually load MIB documents at runtime (like you discovered). MIB to C/Java/C# compilers are usually used only for agents.

Comment: @Jolta MIBs from vendor (UPS from Liebert) don't change a lot.

Comment: As Lex mentioned, loading at runtime is usually more convenient for the user of the manager. That said, it depends on the ambition level of your manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work in the telecoms domain, and most managers I've seen will take the SNMP OIDs for a "node" (telecom slang for equipment) either as a hardcoded strings in a software module, or as configuration in some proprietary files. None of them load the MIB itself since it usually lacks a lot of semantic information such as what thresholds are appropriate for a counter value. HP TeMIP, for instance, takes the former approach, requiring for new MIB integration that an Access Module is developed in C++, which provide alarm adaptation functionality.

That said, an SNMP manager application in its most basic form will not necessarily have such functionality and may be fully content with using the MIB to finding the mapping from OID to variable name and type. In that case, parsing at run time should be most convenient for the end user.